# Como garantir que uma função que depende do ngOnInit seja executada depois dele?

Tags: javascript, promises, angular, angularjs-services

Tenho uma classe que ao ser inicializada recupera dados de um serviço e popular um de seus atributos, que é um *array*. Essa classe tem uma função que ordena esse *array*, filtra e retorna o resultado.

Ao instanciar um objeto desta classe e chamar esta função percebi que a função é chamada antes de terminar a execução do construtor e do `ngOnInit()`. Acredito que isto ocorra por conta do uso da chamada assíncrona ao serviço, que usa *Observables*.

Como posso garantir que isto não aconteça?

```
export class BaseChoice implements PickAppraiser, OnInit {
    weight = 0;
    options = new Array<PickQuality>();

    constructor(private championService: ChampionService) {}

    ngOnInit() {
    // Iterates through the list of champions adding them to the current object
    this.championService.getChampions()
        .subscribe(champions => {
            // Iterates through the list of champions adding them to the current object
            Object.keys(champions).map(key => this.options.push(new PickQuality(champions[key], 0)))
        })
    }

    choose(n?: number): PickQuality[] {
        var sorted = this.options.sort((a, b) => a.score - b.score);
        return sorted;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No caso, já tive um problema parecido com o método get, eu usei um return ai a função deve retornar o que meio faz com que espere a resposta antes de terminar o método

```
ngOnInit() {
// Iterates through the list of champions adding them to the current object
return this.championService.getChampions()
    .subscribe(champions => {
        // Iterates through the list of champions adding them to the current object
        Object.keys(champions).map(key => this.options.push(new PickQuality(champions[key], 0)))
    })
}
```

O método de serviço precisa ter um retorno, acredito que isso resolva.

Comment: O método getChampions() já retorna um Observable, o qual eu pego no ngOnInit(). O problema é garantir que o onInit() seja executado antes da choose(). Pensei em resolver isso chamando a getChampions() na choose() também, mas parece uma solução ruim.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode garantir a execução usando **Promise** porém não vai ficar mais **Assíncrono**.

```
const promiseChampion = new Promise(resolve => { 
resolve(this.championService.getChampions().toPromise()) 
});

promiseChampion.then(value => { 
//código que deverá ser executado caso de certo 
// value trás o valor que sua api deve retornar
});

promiseChampion.catch(error => {
// caso de erro vai vir parar aqui
// error trás o erro ocorrido
});
```

Veja se é isto que vc precisa.

No caso você colocaria a Promise dentro do **ngOnInit**